# How to add data class values to dynamo db using java aws sdk v2?

Tags: kotlin, amazon-dynamodb

I have a data model that I want to insert into dynamo db:

```
data class Bar(val value1: String, val value2: String){
    override fun toString(): String{
        return "$value1.$value2"
    }
}

data class Foo(
    val id: Bar,
    val key: String,
    val count: Int,
    val ts: Long,
    val version: Int

)
```

I am using the following code to insert an item into dynamodb:

```
    val ts = System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
    val id = Foo.id.toString()
    val key = Foo.key
    val count = Foo.count.toString()
    val version = Foo.version.toString()

    val items = mapOf(
        "id" to AttributeValue.builder().s(id).build(),
        "key" to AttributeValue.builder().s(key).build(),
        "count" to AttributeValue.builder().n(count),
        "ts" to AttributeValue.builder().n(ts).build(),
        "version" to AttributeValue.builder().n(version).build()
    )

    val request = PutItemRequest.builder()
        .item(items)
        .tableName(tableName)
        .build()
    dynamoDB.putItem(request)
```

However the compiler complains a type mismatch:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
(Mutable)Map<String!, AttributeValue!>!
Found:
Map<String, SdkPojo!>
```

Is there any way I can convert my data class value to attribute values ?

Answer (score 0):

One should use `DynamoDbEnhancedClient`

eg: This how you can map your classes to DynamoDB tables:

```
val fooTable: DynamoDbTable<Foo> = dynamoDB.table(
    "Foo", TableSchema.fromBean(Foo::class.java))

fooTable.putItem(Foo)
```